# Python - About variable declaration

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can't think of a fitting title for my question.

So anyway, I've been looking for an algorithm to find out if a list is balanced or not and I've came across this question: [Algorithm for finding if an array is balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430702/algorithm-for-finding-if-an-array-is-balanced)

One of the answers is spot-on to what I need to accomplish. I would however, like to understand what happens if I change line 2 from the below code.

```
def balanced(numbers):
    left_total, right_total = 0, sum(numbers)
    for pivot, value in enumerate(numbers):
       if left_total == right_total:
        return pivot
    left_total += value
    right_total -= value
    return None
```

I would like to know why it throws a **TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable** if I do this to line 2:

```
left_total = 0
right_total = 0
sum(numbers)
```

Hope someone can help me understand.
Thanks!

Comment: `right_total` is being assigned with the value of `sum(numbers)`. Not 0

Comment: Those three lines *won't* throw that error. They also don't do the same thing as the one they're replacing.

Comment: and numbers is a list , that's what the error is saying

Comment: `left_total, right_total = 0, sum(numbers)` will assign `left_total` -> 0 and `right_total` -> sum(numbers)

Comment: I wasn't actually asking about the TypeError but rather the way the variables were declared.
My assumption was:

`left_total, right_total = 0, sum(numbers)`

Is equivalent to:

`left_total = 0
right_total = 0
sum(numbers)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "numbers" variable you're passing in is an int.

You can't do sum(1) for example but you can do sum([1,2]) or sum((1,2))

The variable you pass to balanced must be an iterable type.  AKA a list, a tuple, a set, etc.

Unrelated to your error:

You should not be doing

```
left_total = 0
right_total = 0
sum(numbers)
```

but rather

```
left_total = 0
right_total = sum(numbers)
```

If you want to mimic what the function was doing.

For more on the left_total, right_total issue see: [Is there a standardized method to swap two variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python)

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to ask but I wasn't sure how to phrase my question. :)